# Magento adding new customer account navigation link

Tags: magento, hyperlink, navigation, account

I have issue adding new customer account navigation link which is password.phtml on my customer account dashboard. I look at some post here but i am a bit confuse as i am new in Magento. Below is my set of code.

Created /customer/account/password.phtml

My module is Don_Configs.xml

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Don_Configs>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Don_Configs>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Added to local.xml

```
<customer_account translate="label">
   <reference name="left">
    <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer">
        <name>password</name>
        <path>customer/password/</path>
        <label>Password</label>
        </action>
    </block>
   </reference>
</customer_account>
```

My Password.php

```
 <?php
    class Don_Configs_Block_Password extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
     public function _prepareLayout()
      {
          return parent::_prepareLayout();
      }
  }
?>
```

My PasswordController.php

```
<?php

class Don_Configs_PasswordController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
   public function indexAction()
    {         

        if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
        {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account'));
            return false;
        }    
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Update Password'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

}

?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: could you paste config.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

try update your local.xml with this

```
<customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label">
                <name>password</name>
                <path>customer/password/</path>
                <label>Password</label>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
```

Comment: Hi Ansyori. Thanks for your reply mate. I have things working now. :)

Comment: @user3364265, I believe you should accept this as an answer, if it worked for you. And for future, better place for magento questions would be [magento stackexchange site](http://magento.stackexchange.com)